# convert into camel case based on the string position

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<title>1. IN AGENTS IN GENERAL</title>
```

Here i'm trying to convert this into camel case, and if there are a set of words, if they occur they have to be changed into lower case. But the condition is, `if these words come in starting, they have to be changed into camel case, else lower case`.

And my XSL is

```
<xsl:template match="title">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="title/page"/>

   <xsl:param name="Conjunction">^(of|to|and|the|for|on|or|an|as|by|of|it|between|with|in|into|on|onto|here|a)$</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="title/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w)(\w*)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of
          select="if (matches(., $Conjunction, 'i'))
                  then lower-case(.)
                  else concat(upper-case(regex-group(1)), lower-case(regex-group(2)))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

and as per the input the Expected output should be

```
1. In Agents in General
```

but what is get is

```
1. in Agents in General
```

here is the working demo. [DEmo](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTz6/1)

please let me know how can i get this done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume a full-stop delimits each sentence, and you want the first word of each sentence to be capitalised regardless, you could tokenize the text by full-stop...

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\.')">
```

You then apply your regular expression on each part separately, but include a check on the position in the matching-substring so that it doesn't convert the first match to lower case.

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="title/text()">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\.')">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">.</xsl:if>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w)(\w*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of
              select="if (matches(., $Conjunction, 'i') and position() > 2)
                      then lower-case(.)
                      else concat(upper-case(regex-group(1)), lower-case(regex-group(2)))"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just a small question, if i have something like `1)` in another case

Comment: Try changing the regex in the analyse-string to `([a-zA-Z])(\w*)`

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, try changing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (matches(., $Conjunction, 'i'))
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (matches(., $Conjunction, 'i') and position() != 3)
```